# "other tools" vs "others tools"

Tags: plural-forms, comparison, determiners

> 1. We compare our tools with **others** state-of-the-art tools.
> 2. We compare our tools with **other** state-of-the-art tools.

May I know which one is grammatical?

Answer (score 5):

When used as a *[determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)*, "[other](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other#Determiner)" has no plural form with "s". It already fits the plural noun "tools". Hence, only sentence 2 will be grammatical in your example. In your example, the word "other" is a determiner because it serves the noun word "tools", it does not stand alone.

> **Our tools** are state-of-the art. **Other tools** are also state-of-the-art.

See? We don't write "ours tools": the determiners are not used this way. The determiner "our" already fits the plural use as well as the determiner "other".

Here's an example:

> **That** apple is red. (singular "apple")
>   **Those** apples are red. (okay: for plural "apples" we use "[those](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/those#Determiner)", the plural form of "that")
>   **Thats** apples are red. (wrong: we do not add "*s*" to turn the determiner "that" into a "plural determiner").

The determiner "other" is like the determiner "those": it fits plural nouns. There is a morphologically distinct determiner "another" for singular nouns:

> We compared our tool with **another** state-of-the-art tool.

The word "other" has the s-plural form when used as a *[noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other#Noun)*:

> Our tools are better compared with **others**.

If you use an apostrophe after "others", it might become grammatical, since then it will become a noun:

> We compare our tools with **others'** state-of-the-art tools.
>   (meaning: "We compare our tools with state-of-the-art tools made by **others**")

Comment: +1 especially for the last para which conveys everything to the OP! :)